# Python iterating over matrix class

Tags: python, class, iterable

```
from collections.abc import Sequence

class Map(Sequence):
    """ Represents a map for a floor as a matrix """

    def __init__(self, matrix):
        """ Takes a map as a matrix """
        self.matrix = matrix
        self.height = len(matrix)
        self.width = len(matrix[0])
        super().__init__()

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        """ Needed by Sequence """
        return self.matrix[item]

    def __len__(self):
        """ Needed by Sequence """
        return len(self.matrix)

    def search(self, entity):
        """ Returns a generator of tuples that contain the x and y for every element in the map that matches 'entity' """
        for row in range(self.height):
            for column in range(self.width):
                if matrix[row][column] == entity:
                    yield (row, column)


# Examples

gmap = Map([[0, 0, 0],
           [0, 1, 0],
           [0, 0, 0]])

for entity in gmap:
    print(entity)
```

How can I implement`__iter__` so that

```
for entity in gmap:
    print(entity)
```

yields `0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0` and not

```
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
```

This would save me from needing to subclass `Sequence` and would make the code for `search()` neater

Additionally, are their any other magic methods I should be using? (aside from `__str__`, im doing that after I get iterating working)

Comment: That is a really bad idea. It would make your `__iter__` and `__getitem__` inconsistent with each other.

Comment: Also, it wouldn't actually make `search` any neater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may implement `__iter__()` like so:

```
from itertools import chain

def __iter__(self):
    return chain.from_iterable(self.matrix)
```

`itertools.chain.from_iterable()` takes an iterable of iterables and combines them all together. It creates a generator thus does not use extra memory.

Comment: Thanks! I actually tried this, but I just realized I had messed up how to import it

Comment: @Lord_Zane55 btw, a matrix is not necessarily a "sequence of rows"... `__getitem__` returning a row is rather funny. It's not very intuitive.

Comment: I found that snippet online for iterating, could you explain how a matrix is not a "sequence of rows" and what `__getitem__` should be doing for future use?

Comment: @Bharel: `__getitem__` returning a row is perfectly ordinary. How else would you make `some_matrix[2][3]` work?

Comment: I mean, matrix is not a sequence at all. What's a matrix's length? The count of rows? Don't you find it funny that a matrix of 1 row and 9001 columns has a **length** of 1? It has width and height, not length... True, `__getitem__` is needed. The inheritance of `Sequence` is what makes me curious. You might argue that a length is therefore `width * height`, but then `__getitem__` is rather meaningless combined with the length. Trying to get the 9001st item (after all, that's the length) will fail.